# List operations with different results

Tags: python

I would like to understand why I'm getting different results in these lists operations.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list1.remove('a')
print(list1) #results ['b', 'c']

text = "abc"
print(list(text).remove('a')) #results Nome
```

Comment: @Epsi95 it is actually in place, that's why it outputs nothing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list(text).remove('a')` operation is in place, is returns None.

You should do this instead:

```
my_list = list(text)
my_list.remove('a')
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `remove` retuns `None` value.
If you try the same thing with the first case, you will observe the same behavior:

```py
list1 = ['a','b','c']
print(list1.remove('a'))
```